# Excel VBA, import the names of all files in the folder without using Application.FileDialog()

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder (every time it's the same one - so I don't need to waste time to pick it with Application.FileDialog)  and I need to extract all files names into the Excel column C.

This is the code that I've found here on stackoverflow with Application.FileDialog(), but I would like to hard code the path to the folder (C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\mstcgl_csv).

Another Question I have (important) what is $ sign at the end of the xDirectory$, xFname$ and InitialFoldr$ variables, and why I can't declare them `as String` ? ?
Are these variables are not string ? ?

this is the code:

```
Sub GetFileNames()    
  Dim Lista As Worksheet              
  Dim xRow As Long                     
  Dim xDirectory$                     
  Dim xFname$                         
  Dim InitialFoldr$

  Dim start As Double    
  Dim finish As Double    
  Dim total_time As Double

  start = Timer              ' remember time when macro starts.

     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lista").Range("C1").Select

     InitialFoldr$ = "C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\"

     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
         .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
         .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
         .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
         .Show                           ' creates list of files  ? ? ?

          If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then                  
                xDirectory$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"  
                xFname$ = Dir(xDirectory$, 7)
                    Do While xFname$ <> ""
                         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lista").ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = xFname$
                         ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xFname$                         
                         xRow = xRow + 1             
                         xFname$ = Dir               
                    Loop                            
         End If
    End With
   finish = Timer                   ' Set end time.   
  total_time = Round(finish - start, 3)    ' Calculate total time.   
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & total_time & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Can U guys help me do it?
I'm just learnig my VBA basics, and I still don't understand many things. 
And please answer the $ sign question please  :-)

Comment: `Dim xFname$` is a shorthand of `Dim xFname as String`, only less readable, so usually you do not see it too often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrap the `FileDialog` and use the `Dir` function directly:

```
Sub GetFileNames()

    Const InitialFoler As String = "C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\"

    Dim Lista As Worksheet
    Dim filename As String
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim start As Double, finish As Double, total_time As Double

    start = Timer              ' remember time when macro starts.
    xRow = 1

    filename = Dir(InitialFoler & "*.*")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lista")
        Do While Len(filename) > 0
            .Range("C" & xRow).Value = filename
            xRow = xRow + 1
            filename = Dir
        Loop
    End With

    finish = Timer                   ' Set end time.
    total_time = Round(finish - start, 3)    ' Calculate total time.

    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & total_time & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub
```

You can read more about the `Dir` function [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php).

Answer (score 2):

This line writes the path from `Application.FileDialog` into a string:

```
xDirectory$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
```

Now you just need to hardcode your folder to that string instead:

```
xDirectory$ = "C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\"
```

and remove all the code related to the `FileDialog` part.

As for the "$" part, see @BrakNicku's answer above.